# Error: Invalid index while accessing an element in tuple in terraform v0.12.31

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am getting this error

```
Error: Invalid index 
module.thoughtspot_app_vpc.application_subnet_ids is empty tuple
```

for the following code in terraform v0.12.31 . It was working fine in the previous version V0.11.15.

Please suggest

```
resource "aws_instance" "thoughtspot-01-ec2" {
  ami  = var.ami-nw
  instance_type = var.environment == "dev" ? var.instance_type1 : var.instance_type2
  subnet_id = var.environment == "prod" ? module.thoughtspot_app_vpc.application_subnet_ids[1] : module.thoughtspot_app_vpc.application_subnet_ids[0]
}
```

Comment: Can you add the module outputs to the question? Because without knowing what is happening there, we can't really help. Having the entire module could would be even better.

Comment: This is a resource which creates an EC2 instance by using ami, instance_type, subnet id etc.

Comment: Sure, but this is the issue: `module.thoughtspot_app_vpc.application_subnet_ids`. Since there is no information about that output nor where it gets the value from, there is no telling what the problem is except that the output is empty.

Comment: needs more info otherwise the only answer is "you're trying to access an index on an empty tuple"

Comment: In essence, I have a VPC called thoughtspot_app_vpc that has been set up and there is a bunch of information I need to access via the terraform 0.12.31. 
In this case I need to return the subnet ids based on environment . My problem is that I can’t seem to access them from the tuple.

My question  is that why this tuple empty error was not coming in the previous version 0.11.15 ? There is no code change done for this vpc/subnet apart from version upgrade.